# Headless/GUIless automation with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless-browser

I would like to save some resources on my low-spec Windows boxes by running the browser in a headless mode. As far as I am aware, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) + [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) is the standard choice for such task to be used with Selenium Webdriver. However after trying it and immediately running into issues with alerts handling which [doesn't seem to be supported by PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/056aa50c19b31de967ec7c30e59c6cb16680e48d/src/ghostdriver/session.js#L55). Specifically, the following exception is returned:

```
[ERROR - 2016-08-01T04:24:24.894Z] RouterReqHand - _handle.error - {"name":"Invalid Command Method"," . . . "}
```

as a result of not supporting `getAlertText` WebDriver `Command` when performing:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

and specifically this method implemented in `EventFiringWebDriver`:

```
public Alert alert() {
  return targetLocator.alert();
}
```

I am looking for an alternative approach or a feasible workaround. Anyone?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't seem to be supported by PhantomJS?? It just mean alert will not be handle by driver itself you need to handle it by switching to alert and accept or dismiss according to your choice...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I mean that `getAlertText` WebDriver  `Command` is not supported internally and will return an exception. See my edit.

Comment: You are calling wrong method. It's `alert.getText();` instead..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to work around that by executing the alert handling using JavaScript directly like this:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("window.alert = function(){}");
jsExecutor.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");
```

At the moment, there seem to be no way to perform that operation directly via `WebDriver` interface for PhantomJS.

Comment: Also the solution if you run chrome canary in headless mode, thank you!